# Installing Gambit in Terminal on Docker

Tags: docker, terminal, installation

I am using the docker version of Gambit (The Global and Modular Beyond-the-Standard-Model Inference Tool) basically a software on docker platform. And I am working with OS X Sierra, and when I compile it, and I run the following commands:

```
($ mkdir build

cd build 

cmake ..

make)
```

then I get error

> c++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)

(I have attached the whole thing, and there is no such file as `//usr/share/doc/gcc-6/README.Bugs`)

I am wondering if anyone can help me with this issue.

[image]

Comment: I have Improved formatting and embedded the image (for better readability)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MobyVM in which docker run has 2GB memory limit by default. Sometime these compilations require decent amount of memory to be available

[image: Memory settings]

You should try and increase the memory to 4GB or even higher and then try your docker run statement again